# Can min_wal_size bigger than max_wal_size?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, database-tuning, write-ahead-logging, pg-logical

is it possible if `min_wal_size` bigger than `max_wal_size` ? What happen if it does ? What are the circumstances when min_wal is bigger than max_wal ?

I am using PG 12.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try and then tell us?

Comment: Yes. Good point. I don't know the real implication on the production system, that's why I ask before I do something horrible. I am asking this in relation to why there are so many WAL files in the directory. Someone told me that I should reduce my `max_wal_size` to 80MB from previously 4GB, although I have told that my `min_wal_size` is 1GB. So I am humbly asking what the implication of this ? I did tried it, but I haven't seen any difference. Maybe I should turn on `archive_mode` ON. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `min_wal_size` can be bigger than `max_wal_size`. Despite the similar names, these settings are not related to each other.

`max_wal_size` will trigger checkpoint after so many wal writes.

`min_wal_size` will always recycle wal files for future use (rather than removed) as long as WAL disk usage stays below this setting. Can be used for guaranteed space reservation for a future WAL writes.